# Elixir - Nested Route _Paths in Heex templates?

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm relatively new to Elixir and Phoenix so sorry if this is a dumb question.

When trying to figure out nested routes I am getting the following error:

```
function QWeb.Router.Helpers.comment_path/2 is undefined or private
or 
function QWeb.Router.Helpers.post_comment_path/2 is undefined or private
```

Using https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html

I'm currently assuming its an arity error caused by me not knowing what I need to edit when making nested routes, as I get a warning when starting the server flagging my Heex files within the comment folder asking me if I meant to use:

```
      * post_comment_path/3
      * post_comment_path/4
      * post_comment_path/5
      * post_path/2
      * post_path/3
```

Currently my router:

```
    resources "/posts", PostController do 
      resources "/comments", CommentController
    end
```

If I run mix.phx.routes I get the following:

```
       post_comment_path  GET     /posts/:post_id/comments               
       post_comment_path  GET     /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit      
       post_comment_path  GET     /posts/:post_id/comments/new           
       post_comment_path  GET     /posts/:post_id/comments/:id           
       post_comment_path  POST    /posts/:post_id/comments               
       post_comment_path  PATCH   /posts/:post_id/comments/:id           
                          PUT     /posts/:post_id/comments/:id          
       post_comment_path  DELETE  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id
```

I'm able to go to http://localhost:4000/posts and render the page fine. I can create a post and get http://localhost:4000/posts/1.

If I then go to http://localhost:4000/posts/1/comments/new I get the error above stating the comment_path is undefined or private because of the Heex template errors.

The path works if I delete the below content from the prebuilt new.html.heex file

```
<%= render "form.html", Map.put(assigns, :action, Routes.comment_path(@conn, :create)) %>

<span><%= link "Back", to: Routes.comment_path(@conn, :index) %></span>
```

I've tried changing both to post_comment_path(@conn etc as well to match what it says in the router but I just get the same error with the additional post_ prefixed on to it.

If I un-nest(?) the routes and go to http://localhost:4000/comments I obviously have no issues creating comments alone as its the same as posts with a different name. So Routes.comment_path works when its not nested.

So I think my first question is where do I even start? Is this something I need to edit in the controller, the heex document, the view or alias somewhere? All the information I can find on nested routes just seems to show you how to nest the routes and see the paths that are meant to be generated in the router. I can't find any information anywhere on how to access nested routes using Routes._path within Phoenix

Any info appreciated and sorry again if this is obvious.

Comment: Hi, you might want to show your code and error message for post_comment_path. A newly generated heex template may not consider a nested path in routes, so it's possible that it generated an incorrect route path and you must fix it manually in the template. Note that the route path is generated dynamically by path helper based on your router.ex entries. To verify the route path is working you can test in iex with the following example code from docs
`alias HelloWeb.Endpoint
HelloWeb.Router.Helpers.post_comment_path(Endpoint, :show, POST_ID, COMMENT_ID)
"/posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id"`

Comment: It's literally just a barebones template using the nested routes shown in the Hexdocs. The code is nothing more than adding posts and comments through mix.phx.gen.html then adding the resources to the Router. I've made some progress since making this post but still struggling. It's really hard finding information on what the rules are passing values in heex <%= render %> tags when you're new.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact code you are doing

> I've tried changing both to post_comment_path(@conn etc as well to
> match what it says in the router but I just get the same error with
> the additional post_ prefixed on to it.

However, if you are doing the nested version, remember that

```
<%= render "form.html", Map.put(assigns, :action, Routes.comment_path(@conn, :create)) %>
```

Won't work since there is no such route. I think you know this already. If you replace for the post_ as you said, just be sure that it looks as follow

```
<%= render "form.html", Map.put(assigns, :action, Routes._post_comment_path(@conn, :create, POST_ID)) %>
```

POST_ID being the post id otherwise it will fail as not defined.

Regarding nested or non-nested, it depends on you and what API you want to expose. Both should work (assuming you fix the errors you are having).

Hope it helps :)